# Ajax.BeginForm OnSuccess is opening a new window in IE and firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, ajax.beginform

I have an ajax.begin form in one of my views. When I add OnSuccess = (javascript function), in chrome and firefix, it opens a new window. All I am doing in the JS function is to remove a text from the field. In IE it works fine, it doesnt open a new window -

CODE -

```
 <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendMessages", "Chat", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Chat", action = "SendMessages", id = Model.MeetingID }), new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "Information" , OnSuccess="clearText"}))
          {%>
    $(function clearText() {
        $('#SentMessage').val("");
        return false;
});
```

Could some one tell me what I am doing wrong or is it a problem with chrome and firefox ?

Comment: Why is your function definition inside of a document ready handler?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `clearText` function can't be found cause it's not global. It must not be inside $. You can move it outside $ or force it to be global, as the following:

```
window.clearText = function() {
    $('#SentMessage').val("");
}
```

Hope this helps